# Laravel 5: Relations through several tables

Tags: laravel-5, database-relations

I have the following models: Merchant, Product and Store:

Merchant:

```
class Merchant extends Model
{
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Product:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function merchants() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Merchant');
    }


    public function stores() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Store');
    }
}
```

Store:

```
class Store extends Model
{
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

In my MerchantController, I have the following method `show()`:

```
public function show() {

    $merchants = Merchant::selectRaw('merchants.*, REPLACE(abstract, \'[[name]]\', name) AS abstract')
    ->with('products')
    ->where('active', 'yes')
    ->Paginate(10);

    dd($merchants);

    //return view('merchants', compact('merchants'));
}
```

How can I access the stores, the several products are in? I tried `->with(['products', 'stores'])` and got an error:
`Call to undefined relationship [stores] on model [App\Merchant].`

What can I do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel's `hasManyThrough` relationship

in your `Merchant` model
add this relationship

```
public function stores()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Store::class, Product::class);
}
```